# Reverse The Words In A Sentence But Not The Letters

Tags: javascript, java, netbeans

I want to make a program to reverse the words only, not the letters.

For example...

```
i love india
```

... should become...

```
india love i
```

Another example...

```
 google is the best website
```

... should become...

```
 website best the is google
```

With spaces I have thoroughly researched on it but found just nothing.
My logic is that I should just give you my program that is not working.  If you find a small error in my code please give the solution for it and a corrected copy of my program.  Also, if you are not too busy, can you please give me the logic in a flow chart.

[my logic is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq5Lg.png)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Where is your code that you have tried ?

Comment: This is not do my code site

Comment: @user7294900 As you can see in the answers: it actually is, because no matter how bad a question is, someone still wants to farm reputation. (And yes, that's a bad thing :( ...)

Comment: Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/fwpuqfoa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Solution {
     public String reverseWords(String s) {
        if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
            return "";
         }

    // split to words by space
    String[] arr = s.split(" ");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (!arr[i].equals("")) {
            sb.append(arr[i]).append(" ");
        }
    }
    return sb.length() == 0 ? "" : sb.substring(0, sb.length() - 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.
Store the words of each line in a string array.
2.
Print the elements of the array from the last item to the first.